# How to integrate and visualize data from couchDB to Jupyter?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, visualization, couchdb, jupyter-lab

I have been trying to access an database from couchDB through jupyter that can be visualized in JupyterLab. I have tried looking for solution but the data is not being displayed.

I have tried the following code but i believe its not sufficient:

```
import couchdb

couch= couchdb.Server('https://username:password@localhost:0000/')

db = couch\['dummydata'\]

db.resource.head()

rows = db.view('\_all_docs', include_docs=True)

data = \[row\['doc'\] for row in rows\]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = pd.read_csv('dummycht.csv')

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

display(df)
```

Comment: This post is very vague presently and the included code is not supplying much information specific to what you write about in the title and the top of the post. What happens when you run the first two lines and provide your user information? Then when you run `type(couch)`? And then this line `db = couch\['dummydata'\]` problematic to me? I think the slashes are going to cause errors. Are you sure importing `couchdb` doesn't have an object calle `couch` that you are then clobbering with `couch= couchdb.Server(' ...`?